# Obter nome da classe de um objeto

Tags: javascript, html

Quero obter o nome da classe de um elemento SVG. Tenho o seguinte exemplo, mas não obtenho o seu nome:

```
class_obj = document.getElementbyId("id").className; 
console.log(class_obj);
```

exemplo Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/twsthyds/34/

Comment: Não entendi, você quer pegar o que esta dentro da tag <image> no caso o nome da classe que é img1 ou img2 ?

Comment: Seria melhor colocar o código do JSFIDDLE num snippet.

Comment: Quero obter apenas a class, em vez de obter o id de cada elemento

Comment: Talvez isso também ajude http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8010/como-adicionar-e-remover-classes-ao-clicar-em-um-path-svg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vamos lá.

Primeiro, vamos alterar a forma que você está obtendo a classe, para isso:

```
 class_obj = document.getElementById(ddData.element.id).className.baseVal;
    console.log(class_obj);
```

Você está usando a string `"id"` e isso não é o id que você quer. Dessa forma estamos passando o ID da imagem para capturar o elemento. Feito isso, basta obter a classe do mesmo.

Ou podemos utilizar o [.getAttribute("class")](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) para obter a classe do elemento. Ficaria assim o seu código:

```
document.getElementById(ddData.element.id).getAttribute("class");
    console.log(class_obj);
```

Olhe um exemplo funcionando:

```js
var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
  
 var shape = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "image");

 svg.appendChild(shape);
 svg.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedown);
 
 var ddData = {
  element: null,
  initialX: 0,
  initialY: 0,
  originalX: 0,
  originalY: 0,
  finalX: 0,
  finalY: 0,
  contadorElementos: 1,
  movidos: {},
  index: 0
 };

 //start move 
 function mousedown(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var evt = e || window.event;
   ddData.element = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
   if (!ddData.element || ddData.element.tagName == 'svg' || ddData.movidos[ddData.element.id]) return ddData.element = null;
   ddData.element.parentNode.appendChild(ddData.element.cloneNode(true));
   
   //img1
   if (ddData.element.id == "img1"){
    ddData.element.id = 1;
   }
   //img2
   if (ddData.element.id == "img1"){
    ddData.element.id = 2;
   }
   ddData.initialX = evt.clientX;
   ddData.initialY = evt.clientY;
   ddData.originalX = parseFloat(ddData.element.getAttributeNS(null, ddData.element.tagName != 'circle' ? 'x' : 'cx'));
   ddData.originalY = parseFloat(ddData.element.getAttributeNS(null, ddData.element.tagName != 'circle' ? 'y' : "cy"));
   var type = ddData.element.getAttribute('data-type');
      var arrTmp = document.querySelectorAll('[data-type="'+type+'"]');
      
      if(arrTmp.length>3){
        var el = arrTmp[0];
        el.parentNode.removeChild( el );
      }
 };
 
 
 var position_souris_x = [];
 var position_souris_y = [];
 var index_objet = []; 
 

     
 svg.onmousemove = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var evt = e || window.event;
  var el = ddData.element;
  if (el) {
   var posX = ddData.originalX + evt.clientX - ddData.initialX;
   var posY = ddData.originalY + evt.clientY - ddData.initialY;
   
   if (el.tagName != 'circle') {
    el.setAttributeNS(null, "x", posX);
    el.setAttributeNS(null, "y", posY);
   }
   ddData.finalX = posX;
   ddData.finalY = posY;
   
  }
 }
 
 var nombre_image;
 x_sonde = [];
 y_sonde = [];
 x_compteur = [];
 y_compteur = [];
 
 //stops drag movement
 svg.onmouseup = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var evt = e || window.event;
    
  var id = ddData.element && ddData.element.id;
  if (id && !ddData.movidos[id]) ddData.movidos[id] = {
   x: ddData.finalX,
   y: ddData.finalY
  };
  
        //console.log("ID:"+index_objet);
  console.log("ID:"+ddData.element.id);
  
  
  position_souris_x.push(ddData.finalX);
  
  position_souris_y.push(ddData.finalY);  
    
  console.log("x: "+position_souris_x + " y: " + position_souris_y);
  
  nombre_image = position_souris_x.length;
     
   class_obj = document.getElementById(ddData.element.id).className.baseVal;
    console.log('className: ' + class_obj);
    
       class_obj = document.getElementById(ddData.element.id).getAttribute("class");
     console.log('getAttribute: ' + class_obj);
    
  ddData.element = null;
 }
```

```css
    .img{cursor:move;}

.img2{cursor:no-drop;}
```

```html
  <svg width="90%" height="500px">
    <image data-type="img1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/favicon.png" id="1" x="0" y="0" height="20" width="20" class="img1"></image>
    <image data-type="img2" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/favicon1.png" id="img2" x="30" y="0" height="20" width="20" class="img2"></image>
<image></image><image data-type="img1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/favicon.png" id="img1" x="0" y="0" height="20" width="20" class="img1"></image></svg>
```

Seu exemplo editado no [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/twsthyds/35/)

Referência: [SOen.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29454358/4843158)

Answer (score 4):

Se foi bem o que entendi, pegar o valor da classe seria algo assim:

```js
var image = document.getElementsByTagName('image');
console.log(image[0].className);
console.log(image[1].className);
```

```html
<svg width="90%" height=500px>
  <image data-type="img1" xlink:href=/favicon.png id=img1 x=0 y=0 height=20 width=20 class="img1" />
  <image data-type="img2" xlink:href=/favicon1.png id=img2 x=30 y=0 height=20 width=20 class="img2" />
</svg>
```

Neste caso é retornado um objeto com o seguinte valor:

```
 SVGAnimatedString { baseVal="img1",  animVal="img1"}
```

Você pode utilizar o `.baseVal` ou `.animVal` para acessar o valor diretamente.

Answer (score 0):

Caso tenha a ID :

```
document.getElementById("id").className;
```

A diferença está no getElement**ById**
["B" maiusculo]

Outro meio, caso queira acessar pelo tipo:

```
document.querySelector('svg>image').className;
```

Comment: Dessa forma você está retornando um [SVGAnimatedString](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/SVGAnimatedString) e não as classes propriamente ditas. O Autor não explicou bem a pergunta, mas creio que ele quer obter a classe ao clicar na imagem, como mostra o código nele. Seu código está certo, estou apenas deixando uma dica. xD